# ClickOnce component DeploymentUriDifferent exception during deployment from ASP.NET WebForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, deployment, clickonce

We have a ClickOnce component that is installed on a client machine that opens a docx file in Word when a user clicks a URL (in IE11). When we deployed a new release of the component to our QA server for testing, it started to fail during installation with the following `DeploymentException` which doesn't make sense since this worked just fine for all prior releases.

Any thoughts?

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [08/02/2017 3:56:03 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (DeploymentUriDifferent)
    - You cannot start application Company Name Document Handler from this location because it is already installed from a different location.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.CheckDeploymentProviderValidity(ActivationDescription actDesc, SubscriptionState subState)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
    --- Inner Exception ---
    System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentException (DeploymentUriDifferent)
    - You cannot start application Company Name Document Handler from location http://QAserver/Project.Name/ClickOnce/Project.Name.ClickOnce.application 
    it is already installed from location http://localhost/Project.Name.WebClient/ClickOnce/Project.Name.ClickOnce.application. 
    You can start it from location http://localhost/Project.Name.WebClient/ClickOnce/Project.Name.ClickOnce.application 
    or you can uninstall it and reinstall it from location http://QAserver/Project.Name/ClickOnce/Project.Name.ClickOnce.application. 
    If you reinstall the application, be aware that you might lose any customizations that you made to the application.
```

Comment: ClickOnce has auto update feature that enable you to upgrade to a new version without uninstall the previous one. Once you publish a new version to that special URL, your user will receive update information when they run the installed application. They won't be told to uninstall and after several minutes(depending on your application size and download speed) their application will come with updated one. https://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/clickonce-and-expiring-certificates/

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what was happening so far. That's why its a complete mystery to me as to why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: try sending the certificate and having that user install the cert just simply by double clicking on it.

Comment: The certificate has been reinstalled but it did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem turned out to be related to a change in the settings within our `ClickOnce.csproj` file that we didn't realize was checked in by one of our devs.
Specifically, when `Install` is set to `true` and `DisallowUrlActivation` is `false`, we were experiencing the problem. Changing these settings back to what they were originally fixed all issues with ClickOnce installation:

```
<Install>false</Install>
<DisallowUrlActivation>true</DisallowUrlActivation>
```

Hope this helps someone else...